# Maclaurin Series expansion interval

Tags: calculus

I just have a quick question... I solved a Maclaurin series for $\ln(1-8x^5)$ to be $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} (-8x+5)^n,$$ 
but I am not sure what interval the expression would be valid on. If someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Maclaurin expansion for $\ln(1-y)$ is valid when $|y|<1$.
So when we expand $\ln(1-8x^{5})$ we need $|8x^{5}|<1$. In other words, when $|x|<\frac{1}{^{5}\sqrt{8}}$

Comment: How would I write that in interval notation?

Comment: You would write $$-\frac{1}{^5\sqrt{8}}<x< \frac{1}{^5\sqrt{8}}$$, or $$x \in \left[- \frac{1}{^5\sqrt{8}}, \frac{1}{^5\sqrt{8}}\right]$$